# How to populate two combo box in Java from a text file?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

I'm trying to populate two combo boxes from a data but don't know how to divide this data between two combo boxes. The data is populated within two combo boxes now.

here is my data textfile:

```
[Gates]
value1
value2
value3

[Mids]
customer1
customer2
```

and here is my code inside of Java Swing Gui Application:

```
private void populateCombos() throws FileNotFoundException {

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frmGottApplication);

    BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()));
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        textFieldLoadConfig.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        lblConfRes.setText("Loaded " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
    } else {
        lblConfRes.setText("You didn't load...");
    }
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                strings.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String[] lineArrayGates = strings.toArray(new String[] {});

    comboBoxGate.removeAllItems();
    comboBoxMid.removeAllItems();

    for (String str : lineArrayGates) {
        comboBoxGate.addItem(str);
        comboBoxMid.addItem(str);
    }
}
```

As it seen from code i'm reading the data from external text file and then trying to load it within two different combo boxes. But how to write the code that will divide the gate's values to first combo and the mid's values to the second combo.
Any ideas to suggest?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the problem begins with the file and its content, define a property file with a more comfortable format...you can use json, xml, yaml, or just properties...

I will do the example with the old school java properties

the file:

> Gates=value1,value2,value3
>
> Mids=customer1,customer2

then read that as properties, split that to StringArray and populate the Boxes with that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {
    input = new FileInputStream("./file2.txt");
    prop.load(input);
    String[] gates = prop.getProperty("Gates").split(",");
    String[] mids = prop.getProperty("Mids").split(",");
    JFrame myJFrame = new JFrame();
    myJFrame.setTitle("Example");
    myJFrame.setSize(250, 250);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JComboBox<String> myComboGates = new JComboBox<>(gates);
    JComboBox<String> myComboMids = new JComboBox<>(mids);
    panel.add(myComboGates);
    panel.add(myComboMids);

    myJFrame.add(panel);
    myJFrame.setVisible(true);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
    try {
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

}
```

the result is 2 combos with 2 different kind of infos from a prop. file:[image]